# What makes Bluetooth v5.0 completely better than v4.2?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I read documents about Bluetooth 5.0 and one of my first sign is, v5 has longer range, higher speed and also consuming lower power than v4.2 . Actually these features should affect each other by opposite way. If speed and range is better, then power comsuption should be affected in a negative way.

Whats the actual change they did to make 5.0 better than older one. Every feature of it seems better ? Its about data structure ? Whats the key improvement ?

[image]

Comment: I love the line "Digital Life" that says Bluetooth 4.2 is "less better"

Comment: my digital life is less better compare to bt5 too, I'm still using BT4, like a caveman...

Comment: what in the world does `completely better` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, typically you cannot improve *all* aspects at once, there are usually tradeoffs. It appears that Bluetooth 5 increases the data rate and range, but not necessarily at the same time:

> Bluetooth 5 introduced significant changes at the physical (PHY) layer for Bluetooth radio operation. Four data rates are now available 2Mbps, 1Mbps, 500kbps and 125kbps. The 2Mbps clearly offers higher throughput possibilities. Why offer lower datarates of 500kbps and 125kbps some may ask. The reason for these is that at these lower datarates and with the associated LE Coded processing using Forward Error Correction (FEC) it becomes easier to retirieve data transmissions in surrounding noise. In short, the sensitivity improves, specifically by around 12dB.
>
> Link budgets can be improved by additional power, but critically the long range improvements in Bluetooth 5 do not rely on improved output power and mean up to four times more range can be achieved without a need to increase peak output power. The data throughput capacity does of course reduce when 500kbps or 125kbps modes are selected, but for many Bluetooth low energy applications which are relatively straightforward sensing and actuating applications, these data rates are perfectly adequate.

That is, when the signal is strong, the data rate can hit 2Mbps, but if it signal gets weaker, it can continue functioning at reduced rates at a longer distance than older versions allowed.

https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Low-power-short-range-wireless/Bluetooth-5